# client side validation not working for model window / ajax-loaded-form in yii

Tags: ajax, yii, popupwindow

I   am using **Yii-user extension** in the **main layout** i have a sign up link which is common to all the **Cmenu**

view/main layout

```
  echo CHtml::link('Signup','#',array('id'=>'regi'));


  $("#regi").click(function(){


    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/user/registration',
        success:function(res){
            $("#dispdata").show();
            $("#dispdata").html(res);
        }
         });
             });



  <div id="dispdata"><div>
```

**yii user extension **renders this perfectly and even submit its correctly if form values a re valid.

but if the values are incorrect and blank it redirect to url  .../user/registration

which is not what my need .I need guidance what do i do such that if the values are incorrect or blank it should not redirect and display the errors in model window.

I did tried but hardly could get the satisfied results

if i place the following the model window itself doesnt appear what do i do

module registrationController i placed

```
    ....//some code here  (**in yiiuser register controller**)
    if ($model->save()) {
        echo CJSON::encode(array(
                        'status'=>'success',
                        ));

        }

     ....//some code here...

          Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
          $this->renderPartial('registration',array('model'=>$model,),false,true);
```

in module view registration

```
       <?php echo   CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('registration'),CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('user/registration','render'=>false)),array('dataType'=>'json',
        'success'=>'function(data) {
            if(data != null && data.status == "success") {
                $("#registration-form").append(data.data);

            }

        }')); ?>
```

can anyone please guide me am working past 10 ten days tried every hook or crook method but could not obtain the results......how can the model window with client side validation be done appear..... Please guide me or let me know something better can be done

---

rules in registration model

```
   if (!(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='registration-form')) {
        array_push($rules,array('verifyCode', 'captcha',      'allowEmpty'=>!UserModule::doCaptcha('registration')));
```

as well was not with attributes for reqired field

have changed to

```
  array_push($rules,array('verifyCode', 'captcha','message' => UserModule::t("captcha cannot be blank.")));
```

and added the verifycode to required field

yet not working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is using render method in your Ajax action and creating empty layout for this action. If you do so, validation scripts will be included in the server response. Also you need to exclude jquery.js and other script with `Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap` and include them in main layout always.

Comment: Soory for the delay, am a lil confused may be its a silly question but then i dint understand " using render method in your Ajax action" as i dont have ajax action. do you mean i have to create  actionajax in registrationcontrolller  .the  next thing is am not getting is exclude jquery.js and other script with Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap  ....... the thing is i have not written any jquery validate,registration model has validation, does the validation vai ajax if its not rendered in model window ... can u please provide more info

Comment: Thank you:) alex am done with what you said and it works but captcha validation not working ..... i ahve updated my question  with captcha rules and error

Comment: when i leave one or more  textfields it renders the error and not submits the form, doesnt show any error for captcha if i dont fill it its submits but doesnt save it goes to the url - ../../../user/registration and renders the error" Verification Code cannot be blank." the error is not rendered in the model window as other errors are displayed

Comment: only captcha client validation doesnt work doesnt work